# Keras: how to get y_true dimensions inside custom loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to write my custom loss in keras

Assume y_true is image and shape = [B, H, W, C]

```
def myloss(y_true, y_pred, p=10000):

    mask = y_true[0]
    mask_res = mask[:, :, 0] + mask[:, :, 1] * 256 + mask[:, :, 2] * 256 * 256
    mask_res = tf.reshape(mask_res, [mask_res.shape[0] * mask_res.shape[1]])
    ...
```

But i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/mnt/hdd/segmentation/segmentation/main.py", line 73, in <module>
model = ResNet50().setup()
File "/mnt/hdd/segmentation/segmentation/model2.py", line 57, in setup
self.model.compile(optimizer=SGD(momentum=0.9, decay=5e-4), loss=myloss)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 342, in compile
sample_weight, mask)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 404, in weighted
score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "/mnt/hdd/segmentation/segmentation/loses.py", line 11, in myloss
mask_res = tf.reshape(mask_res, [mask_res.shape[0] * mask_res.shape[1]])
File "/home/oradomskyi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3903, in reshape
"Reshape", tensor=tensor, shape=shape, name=name)
File "/home/oradomskyi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 513, in _apply_op_helper
raise err
File "/home/oradomskyi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 510, in _apply_op_helper
preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
File "/home/oradomskyi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1036, in internal_convert_to_tensor
ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
File "/home/oradomskyi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 235, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
File "/home/oradomskyi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
File "/home/oradomskyi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 522, in make_tensor_proto
"supported type." % (type(values), values))
```

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: [Dimension(None)]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.

How i can get shape y_true?

Comment: Could you explain what this line is doing: `mask = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true[0])`?

Comment: @today update. mask = first batch in y_true (in future i will add work with all batch)

Comment: So in which line this error occurs? I don't see anything wrong with the portion of code you have posted. Please include the relevant parts as well as the full stack trace.

Comment: @today Updated.